# Covering a genus g surface with n disks, and conversely

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Suppose $X$ is a closed compact surface (i.e. a compact two-dimensional manifold without boundary).

1. If $X$ has genus $g$, what is the minimum number of (homeomorphic images of) open balls required to cover $X$?
2. If $X$ can be covered by $n$ (homeomorphic images of) open balls, is there an upper bound for the genus of $X$? If so, what's the upper bound?

One can show that if $X$ can be covered by $2$ open balls, then $X$ has to be a sphere (it's a fun exercise so I won't spoil it with further details). Furthermore, it's not too hard to show that a torus can be covered by $3$ open balls. I'm not sure what the situation is for more balls/higher genus though, so I'm content to leave this one with the internet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you only need $3$ open balls to cover any closed oriented compact surface $X$ of $g\geq 1$.

Consider the standard fundamental polygons of $X$, it is a CW complex by identifying the boundary of a $2$-cell with the wedge sum of $2g$ circles. Suppose the intersection point of the $2g$ circles is $p$. Let $B_1$ be the $2$-cell of $X$, $B_2$ be a open neighborhood of $p$ which is homeomorphic to an open $2$-ball, then $X-(B_2\cup B_2)$ is a disjoint union of $2g$ paths, each path is homeomorphic to the closed interval. Finally, choose $B_3$ to cover these $2g$ paths, we are done.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about this proof. How are you identifying the boundary of a $2$-cell with the wedge sum of $2g$ circles? Further, why is there an open neighbourhood of $p$ which is homeomorphic to an open $2$-ball?

Comment: Use the standard fundamental polygon, which is a 4g-polygon, identifying 2g pairs of edges, then it has the CW complex structure of what I said. You can choose $B_2$ as a small open ball centered at $p$.

Comment: Ok, got it! Nice proof, thanks. (It's easier to see it in a picture than in words)